# Blank value is not consider in input [type=text] if value is empty

Tags: html, autofill

I am having simple **HTML** code:

```html
<form action="login_validation.php">
    <input type="text" name="username1" placeholder="Username" value="">
    <input type="password" name="upassword" placeholder="Password" value="">
</form>
```

My output is:

[image]

But, I am confused, why this has happened (auto-filled username and password) even I have assigned the `value=""` (assigned blank value) in HTML.

Why blank value is not consider in HTML?

Comment: Your code is fine. This is probably the browser. You can add autocomplete="off" to your form tag and it will do the trick.

Comment: @kurenaiKunai yes, I agree `autocomplete="off"` is work, but why browser not understand the the value initially blank. and browser set any random user name and password on page load which I have used before without user trigger.

Comment: The browsers have auto form fill features which you can turn off and also clear cache to prevent this from happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Answer (score 1):

Your field are yellow. This means that the auto-complete feature of your browser kicked in and filled your fields for you.

Hence, your HTML is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This will help:

```
<form action="login_validation.php" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username1" placeholder="Username" value="">
    <input type="password" name="upassword" placeholder="Password" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Bradley Gizzi, adding autocomplete parameter to input boxes, as u said, is not a good practice :/

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this by adding the attribute `autocomplete="off"` to the input boxes, though this isn't acknowledged by all browsers

EDIT: Zheka you pretty much just copied my answer.